# Parse.com adding images via URL

Tags: ios, image, url, parse-platform

I just wanted to ask how to add to my Parse TableView via URl some images. I`m stuck with it. I made it with custom cells. Labels works good.Can you help me please with adding imageview? 
Thanks Milan

```
 TableViewController.h

> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> #import "Parse/Parse.h"
> #import "CustomCell.h"
> 
> @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
> <UITableViewDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>  {
>     
>     NSArray *colorsArray;
>     NSArray *searchResults;
>      }
> 
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *colorsTable;
> 
> 
> 
> @end
```

TableViewController.m

> ```
>     @interface TableViewController ()
>
> @end
> @implementation TableViewController
>
>
> @synthesize colorsTable;
>
> - (void) retrieveFromParse {
>
>     PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
>     [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>         if (!error) {
>             colorsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
>         }
>         [colorsTable reloadData];
>     }];
>     [self.colorsTable reloadData];
>     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
> }
>
> - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
> {
>     self = [super initWithStyle:style];
>     if (self) {
>         // Custom initialization
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
>
>     UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
>
>     self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
>
>     [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse)
>      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
> }
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
> {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> #pragma mark - Table view data source
>
> - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
> {
>     // Return the number of sections.
>     return 1;
> }
>
> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {
>     // Return the number of rows in the section.
>     return colorsArray.count;
> }
>
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> {
>     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"colorsCell";
>
>     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>
>     PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>
>     [cell.imageview setFile: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];
>     [cell.imageview loadInBackground];
>
>     cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
>     cell.cellDescript.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];
>
>     return cell;
> }
>
>
>
> @end
> ```

CustomCell.h

> ```
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> #import "Parse/Parse.h"
>
> @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescript;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *imageview;
>
>
> @end
> ```

CustomCell.m

> ```
> #import "CustomCell.h"
>
> @implementation CustomCell
> @synthesize cellTitle;
> @synthesize cellDescript;
> @synthesize imageview;
>
> - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
> {
>     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
>     if (self) {
>         // Initialization code
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
> - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
> {
>     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
>
>     // Configure the view for the selected state
> }
>
> @end
> ```

Comment: Already fixed this problem. [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149468/pfimageview-url-displaying-parse

Comment: I already fixed this problem. [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149468/pfimageview-url-displaying-parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse using `PFImageView` for display a image file(PFile). Change your `UIImageView` to `PFImageVIew`
if you have `xib` file, change your class.
[image]

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *imageview;
```

In `cellForRow`:

```
     [cell.imageview setFile: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];                  
     [cell.imageview loadInBackground];
```

Comment: Thank you for quickly answer. I`ve got one more problem. After I changed UIimageView to PFImageView I can`t connect segue with imageview(via ctrl) and if run the app I get error. Can you help me, please? Thanks a lot

Comment: i updated my answer, change class to PF, and connect with IBOutlet

Comment: Still don`t got it. Don`t know the reason. I think everything is all right. I connected it already. http://postimg.org/image/jys3hqegt/

Comment: It`s probably because of this line [cell.imageview loadInBackground];. Don`t know any others option how to repair.

Comment: The above image is not clear what your problem is, you can create a method to setup cell and pass a PFObject, then write your code to show data in there.

Comment: You mean to upload my custom cells files text?

Answer (score 0):

If someone have a same problem. I already fixed it with With SDWebImage.