# Parse.com PFImageview URL doesn't work

Tags: ios, url, imageview, runtime-error, parse-platform

I'm stuck with parse PFIMageView via URL. I already wrote one question, moved little bit but the app still doesn't work. I put run and got this error, nothing loads.

image with errors : http://postimg.org/image/jys3hqegt/

previous question: [Parse.com adding images via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961263/parse-com-adding-images-via-url/20962354?noredirect=1#comment31503005_20962354)

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end @implementation TableViewController


 @synthesize colorsTable;

 - (void) retrieveFromParse {

     PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
     [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             colorsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
         }
         [colorsTable reloadData];
     }];
     [self.colorsTable reloadData];
     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; }

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
     }
     return self; }
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];


     UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

     self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

     [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     // Return the number of sections.
     return 1; }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
     return colorsArray.count; }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"colorsCell";



 CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [cell.imageview setFile: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];



 [cell.imageview loadInBackground];


 cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];


cell.cellDescript.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];

     return cell; }



 @end
```

Comment: If anyone have the same problem. I already fixed it. [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149468/pfimageview-url-displaying-parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you check the object of the line: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]?

I think you can trace the URL of the object to find some informations.

Comment: I did, I think that everything is ok but I am still getting that error