# PFImageView url displaying parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, parse-platform, sigabrt

It has been 1 week and I am still stuck on PFImageView. I remade everything. Changed from UITableView to PFQueryTableView, then tried to display image with UITableViewCell, then with PFTableViewCell and in every method only things that works to display are labels. Everytime when I run my app I get crash(SIGABRT) because of this line: `

Crashing line

> ```
>  cell.imagevieww.file= [object objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
>         [cell.imagevieww loadInBackground];
> ```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot

TableViewController.h

> ```
> #import <Parse/Parse.h>
> #import "Customcell.h"
> #import "DetailViewController.h"
>
> @interface TableeViewController : PFQueryTableViewController {
>
>     NSArray *colorsArray;
>
> }
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *colorsTable;
>
>
>
>
> @end
> ```

TableViewController.m

```
    #import "TableeViewController.h"
    #import "TableViewCell.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @interface TableeViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation TableeViewController
    @synthesize colorsTable;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
        if (self) {
            // The className to query on
            self.parseClassName = @"Hracky1";

            // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
            self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

            // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
            self.paginationEnabled = NO;
        }
        return self;
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject
*)object {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"colorsCell";
        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }
        cell.imagevieww.file= [object objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
        [cell.imagevieww loadInBackground];

        cell.cellTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
        cell.cellDescript.text = [object objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];



        return cell;
    }

    @end
```

Customcell.h

> ```
> #import <Parse/Parse.h>
>
> @interface TableViewCell : PFTableViewCell
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescript;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *imagevieww;
> @end
> ```

Comment: What is `ImageURL` that you're setting? What line is the crash? What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: I have String class on my parse.com named ImageURL and I want to display the image via url. I am making some list of Toys and have 3 labels Title,Description and price and on the left side of cell I want to display images, which url address I will type on parse.com and it will display same as labels after refresh. I do not want to save images. I can send you photo of storyboard, if you want to check, how do I mean this. Crash line is updated upside. Anyway if I don`t connect via ctrl imagevieww property with PFImageView in storyboards, it doesn`t crash. But shows nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PFImageView` links only to files stored on Parse.com and represented by `PFFile` objects. You can't set `cell.imagevieww.file` to a string and have it work.

If you are using normal URLs to arbitrary images on the web then you should use [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) (or a similar generic solution) for the image view on your cell.

---

With `SDWebImage` you would replace:

```
    cell.imagevieww.file= [object objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
    [cell.imagevieww loadInBackground];
```

with:

```
    [cell.imagevieww setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[object objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Does what work? `PFImageView` works with `PFFile` instances and `SDWebImage` works with arbitrary URLs. Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean that I am in trouble about using Parse.com. My app is made with Parse.com and I just want to display image from url string from Parse.com`s data browser. So I am not sure how to customize SBWebImage with parse. That`s what I needed to know. Hope that you understand me now

Comment: You don't customise `SDWebImage`, you just supply it with a URL created from the string you currently have.

Comment: Thank you!! Finally got it. After 2 weeks it finally works. Thanks a lot